# Should a function that inputs a file referenced by a file pointer rewind the file pointer prior to returning to the caller?

Tags: c

I have a function, `input()`, that is invoked with two parameters:

```
int input(char * a, FILE * fp);
```

The function fills up the array pointed to by `a` from the file pointed to by `fp` and returns the number of characters input.

I can imagine a user of `input()` wanting to invoke the function, inputting data from the same file into a different array. Before doing so, `rewind(fp)` had better have been called.

Question: Whose is responsible for calling `rewind(fp)`, the `input()` function or the user of the function? Should I put `rewind(fp)` at the end of `input()`? What is best practice?

Comment: What if `FILE * fp)` is not seekable? (such as a serial line)

Comment: In addition to @wildplasser's comment: `input()` cannot know what kind of `FILE` it uses, and whether its user wants to call it again with another destination. So I think it's the caller's responsibility. Compare with `scanf()` and other such functions. -- Anyway, this question calls for opinions, which is off-topic on SO.

Comment: @thebusybee The question had to be asked in order to know whether there exists a consensus on the matter. Also, it has value because while people can’t give a definite answer, they can help the reader make the good choice by bringing considerations he may not have thought of (like @wildplasser’s remark does)